# DNSSEC: After signing child zone do I need to work my way up the chain and sign every parent zone?

Tags: dns, dnssec

So working through literature and tutorials DNSSEC is fairly straight forward.  I sign a zone and hand the DS records to the parent zone, which in basic tutorials is your registrar thus completing the chain.

I want to take this a bit further and be able to delegate different sub domains.  My understanding is that these sub domains will have to sign their zone and then give its parent zone the DS records.  My question is, whenever a sub domain signs its zone do I need to take those DS records and update the parent zone then resign the parent zone and so on until I make my way up the chain?

For example this is my current understanding:

1. I register a domain, **example.com**
2. I delegate a zone **production.example.com**.  I sign the zone and give the DS records to **example.com**
3. At some later date in the future I delegate a zone within **production.example.com** called **service1.production.example.com**.  I sign **service1.production.example.com** then pass the DS records to **production.example.com**.  Then I resign **production.example.com** pass its new DS records to **example.com**.

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: `DS` records for `service1.production.example.com` in the `production.example.com` zone needs to be signed (by the ZSK of `production.example.com`), yes. Otherwise there is no chain of trust. But other than that (and NSEC/NSEC3 records) it does not change the other records in the `production.example.com` zone. Signing is per RRset, not globally.

Comment: Also it really matters only if technically delegated, and a `.` (dot) is not always necessary a delegation. Is `service1` really a zone delegated off to its own set of nameservers, separate from `production`?